# Notifying a User that their Appointment is About to Begin using Javascript/jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have just finished creating a `localStorage` booking website for a university project, as an additional feature, I was thinking of including a hidden `span` which would be shown when the users appointment is starting soon. The examples I have looked at for countdowns etc look really complex and my knowledge is limited so I don't know what parts I would need to construct such a thing..

I am just really looking for some advice on how I would go about it. I have a `datepicker` and a `select` box with times (populated from an array) and I want to use the data that is stored from the appointment booking to show a span that says 'Your appointment is about to begin', for example.

Here is my function that displays my bookings in the browser (from `localStorage`)

```
function showBooking() {
    var bookingResult = document.getElementById("result");
    var ul = document.createElement("ul");
    bookingResult.innerHTML = `<h3 class="text-center">Your Bookings</h3>`;
    for (let i = 0; i < bookings.length; i++) {
        bookingResult.innerHTML += `
<div class="card resultcard card-body bg-light  m-4"> 
<div class="row">
<p>Owner name:${bookings[i].fname + " " + bookings[i].lname}</p>
<p>Dog Name: ${bookings[i].dogname + " " + bookings[i].lname} (${bookings[i].breed})</p>
<p>Collecting from ${bookings[i].address + ", " + bookings[i].postcode + " at " + bookings[i].stime + " for a " + bookings[i].duration} dog walk.</p>
<p>Additional Info: ${bookings[i].info}</p>
</div>
<span id="apptNotify" class="label label-success" style="display: none;">Your appointment is about to begin.</span>
<div class="row">
<div class="d-grid gap-2 d-md-block">
<button onclick="editBooking(${i})" class="col-md-4 btn btn-outline-danger ">Edit</button>
<button onclick="deleteBooking(${i})" class="col-md-4 btn btn-danger text-light ">Delete</button>
</div>
</div>                          
</div>`;
    }
}
```

My array of times:

```
function showTimes() {
    let startTime = document.getElementById('stime');

    let times = ['9:00', '9:30', '10:00', '10:30', '11:00', '11:30','12:00','12:30', '13:00', '13:30', '14:00', '14:30', '15:00'];

    let options = times.map(time => `<option value="${time}">${time}</option>`).join('');

    startTime.innerHTML += options;
}
```

And my form elements which contribute to these functions (not the entire form):

```
  <form id="regForm" name="regForm" action="" class="col-md-6">
          <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input type="date" id="sdate" class="input datepicker form-control required" name="sdate" onchange="checkStartDate()" required>
                            <span id="dError" style="display: none;">Start date must be in the future.</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <select name="stime" class="select form-control required" id="stime" required>
                                <option value="" selected disabled hidden>Choose a time</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
</form>

<div id="result" class="result row"></div>
```

Comment: Is this just a demo system where the appointment data is stored in localStorage on the client, or is there a server side data store involved too? I ask as it greatly affects how the solution will need to be created.

Comment: Just a demo system using localStorage, we are not allowed to use any server-side technology as part of the task.

Comment: HI, you can use `setInterval()` inside this you can loop through your localstorage data and check if the `time or date` matches today date then show your span inside your record .